# Solr schema overhead with lots of cores

Tags: solr

I have a Solr server which index billions of logs per day (50k/sec).
For performance reasons I prefer to index every 60M documents (around 20 minutes) in a different core since afterwards the insert rate goes down.
This means I'll have 72 cores per day.
Most searches will be only on the last day, but on some occasions I'll need to search 7-30 days back.
All cores share the exact same schema / settings.
Does Solr knows to hold the schema / settings once for all cores or it will need to create it for each core it loads for query (I'm planning using transient cores and holding only 30 up in a given moment).
I'm specifically concerned about the overhead of loading the schema/settings for tens / hundreds of cores for performing queries.